# Wireless mouse not working when plugged directly to laptop, but works fine when plugged to a USB extension hub

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse

If dongle is plugged directly to laptop, cursor just wiggles a little, or sometimes responds to a right-click.

Some specs:

- Generic (China) wireless mouse with usb dongle.
- Dell Vostro 5560   laptop, running on ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.

Things I've tried:

- plugging the dongle through all available usb3.0 sockets in the laptop (no luck)
- tested mouse on another machine (Dell Inspiron, running peppermint linux 32 bit) (mouse worked Ok)
- using freshly charged batteries.

I was able to make it work once with the dongle attached directly. But when I attached a usb memory stick, response of cursor slowly degraded until it stopped working completely. I can't remember though how I made it work - I was going through a lot of forum posts and now I can't reproduce it.

I'd like to be able to use the mouse w/out the need for the USB 4-port extension hub dangling by my laptop.

Here is `lsusb` with dongle attached to hub, mouse working ok:

```
doc1@Vostro5560:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 5986:0523 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 1bcf:05ca Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is `dmesg` after detaching dongle from hub and attaching directly to laptop, cursor not responding to mouse movements:

```
doc1@Vostro5560:~$ dmesg | tail -20
[27649.736759] usb 1-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[27649.736763] usb 1-3.1: Product: 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver
[27649.737047] usb 1-3.1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[27649.737055] usb 1-3.1: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[27649.744292] input: 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/0003:1BCF:05CA.0015/input/input36
[27649.800099] hid-generic 0003:1BCF:05CA.0015: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
[27649.805355] input: 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.1/0003:1BCF:05CA.0016/input/input37
[27649.860491] hid-generic 0003:1BCF:05CA.0016: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input1
[30245.594538] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 29
[30245.594546] usb 1-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 33
[30254.495342] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[30254.628444] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=05ca
[30254.628452] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[30254.628455] usb 1-3: Product: 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver
[30254.628712] usb 1-3: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[30254.628734] usb 1-3: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[30254.636102] input: 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1BCF:05CA.0017/input/input38
[30254.691952] hid-generic 0003:1BCF:05CA.0017: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[30254.697419] input: 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:1BCF:05CA.0018/input/input39
[30254.752038] hid-generic 0003:1BCF:05CA.0018: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
```

I can copy-paste to and from terminal, I can't interpret the output though.

Edit: 4-port USB extension has a USB2.0 mark on it. Mouse is most likely USB2.0 too, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, and honestly these days, a not so common one anymore. Unfortunately for you, this is not an error that is easy to fix, but it is very easy to tell you why it is happening. USB 2.0 was built to receive only a certain amount and type of information from the device in it, while USB 3.0 was made to receive almost all of it. It seems that the extension you have turns 2.0 into 3.0. So basically, the problem is that your laptop USB 2.0, which isn't supported by your mouse. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a hub with a separate power supply?
Some on-board USB ports don't provide a very high voltage to the power pins in the USB connector. It might be that your laptop is not giving the dongle enough voltage to work with, whereas the hub is providing more power

Comment: Hub is totally powered via the laptop's USB port. The hub has a dc jack, but it's not connected to any power supply.